# Hazelcast - when a new cluster member is merging, is the new member operational?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

When a new member joins a cluster, table repartitioning and data merge will happen.

If the data is large, I believe it will take some time. While it is happening, what is the state of the cache like?

If I am using embedded mode, does it block my application until the merging is completed? or if I don't want to work with an incomplete cache, do I need to wait (somehow) before starting my application operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition migration will start as soon as the member joins the cluster. It will not block your application because it will progress asynchronously in the background.

Only mutating operations that fall into a migrating partition are blocked. Read-only operations are not blocked.

Mutating operations will get `PartitionMigrationException` which is a `RetryableHazelcastException` so they will be retried for default 2 minutes. If you have small partition sizes, then migration of a partition will last shorter. You can increase partition count via system property `hazelcast.partition.count`.

If you want to block your application until all migrations finish, you can check [isClusterSafe](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#ensuring-safe-state-with-partitionservice) method to make sure there are no migrating partitions in the cluster. But beware that isClusterSafe returns the status of the cluster rather than current member so it might not be something to rely on. Instead, I would recommend not to block the application while partitions are migrating.